# Indent 2nd line of a paragraph to line up with first line?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, paragraph, text-indent

I am using [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) to add icons to p:before selectors and I am wondering how I can indent only the 2nd line of the paragraph so that the text is aligned.

Here is what my current output looks like:

[image: Non-indented]

And here is what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: Indented]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="result>
   <p class='fa location'>{{ address }}<br/>{{ citystate }}</p>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.result .location:before {
    content: "\f041";
    padding-right:6px;
    color:#b3b3b3;
}
```

Is it possible to accomplish this as-is? Or will I need to restructure my code to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pad the entire paragraph to the right and then pull the fontawesome icon to the left to fill the space created.

```
.result {
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.result .location:before {
    content: "\f041";
    color:#b3b3b3;
    margin-left: -10px;
    padding-right: 2px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkN82/)

Comment: Thanks that seems to have worked great. I added a 20px padding to the whole paragraph and then added a margin-left of -20px and padding-right to the ':before' class and now it's aligned properly.

Answer (score 0):

What you could add in some `&nbsp;` after the `<br />` and make your code look like this:

```
<div class="result>
   <p class='fa location'>{{ address }}<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ citystate }}</p>
</div>
```

add the `&nbsp;` in until it is moved over as far as you need it.

I hope that helped you out.